# Service activator not working for InboundChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have to read new emails from my gmail account. For that I am using spring integration project. Below is my code

```
    @Component
public class EmailAdapter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private EmailReceiverService emailReceiverService;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "emailChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000"))
    public MailReceivingMessageSource mailMessageSource(MailReceiver imapMailReceiver) throws MessagingException {
        emailReceiverService.messageSource();
        return new MailReceivingMessageSource(imapMailReceiver);
    }

    @Bean
    @Value("imaps://<username>:<password>@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox")
    public MailReceiver imapMailReceiver(String imapUrl) {
        ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(imapUrl);
        imapMailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
        imapMailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        return imapMailReceiver;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "emailChannel")
    public void emailMessageSource(javax.mail.Message message) {
        logger.info("Message received");
    }
}
```

My application boots up properly after and scheduler try to receive email from inbox but when a send a new email to the account, **service activator** is not called at all. I say so because I do not see any logs.

Please check the output once application boots up.

```
     com.test.email.EmailApplication      : Started EmailApplication in 4.807 seconds (JVM running for 5.295)
[ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver    : attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
enter code here
```

What configuration am I missing here? Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

I created a fresh gmail account and tried with that. I was able to read email in case new emails were sent to that account. But when I try to read my email account which is my email account for organisation where I work, It does not work. I think there is some configuration which I am missing.

Comment: Do you have somewhere `@EnableIntegration`? May we see DEBUG logs after starting application? Are there some errors in logs at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/mail). Even though it uses XML for it's configuration, you can easily convert it to annotation-based approach. 
In my experience with Gmail, there are things you need to enable in Gmail account setting and provide additional properties which you can also see from the above example.

Comment: There is also `mail.debug=true` system property to get more info from logs: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug